# Python pynput, pyautogui, keyboard modules - Cannot input letters into keyboard, e.g. automate typing a setnence. Recording inputs works fine

Tags: python, keyboard, pyautogui, pynput

I am on python version 3.8, in VsCode. When trying to automate the typing of a character, there are no compilation problems - it just does not type. Is this a security issue? I have tried giving python computer control, but nothing has worked.

Example Code Below:

```py
import keyboard
import time

time.sleep(3)
keyboard.write("asfdasdfs")
```

Security Settings Image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPH6m.png

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
import pyautogui
import time

time.sleep(3)
pyautogui.typewrite("asfdasdfs")
```

But remember to download Pyautogui library by using `pip install pyautogui` on your cmd